# Windows console applications in Citrix/XenApp/AppV

Tags: streaming, citrix

I have developed some Windows console applications in .NET 4.0. Is it possible to "stream" such console applications using Citrix/XenApp or Microsoft AppV? I couldn't find information about this.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "stream" them.  If you can steam anything using those tools then you can stream a .NET application.

Comment: That's what I can't find out. If those tools can stream .NET console applications.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: No, I haven't because the servers are not under my control. I'm working for a company and have no access to any of these techniques. I have asked the admins without a reply.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested it, but.. what happens when you publish an application via XenApp?  
In a very simple way:  
1. Logon with your profile on the destination server.  
2. "Citrix" will start the application for you (Citrix knows that, because you say the path via application publishing)  
3. "Citrix" will cutting-out and display the content what appears on the destination server

(Yes, I know.. between "I click on an app" and "the application appears" happens much more like these three things..)

Comment: Ditto.  http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/507632.  BTW, several of these questions are very old.  Answering old questions is encouraged, but that's not always possible if the original poster is long gone and can't clarify anything.  You can click on the poster's link on the question to bring up their profile to see if they're still around to provide clarification.